# Sequelize find this OR that

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do a `find` with Sequelize that returns a record matching either a `username` or an `email`.  Is it possible to do this with one call?  I have something like:

```
User.find({
  where: { 
    username: "bryan", 
    email: "bryan@foo.com"
  }
}).then(...)
```

But this does `username` `AND` `email`; I need `username` `OR` `email` to match.

I could easily do this in 2 DB calls, but is it possible to do it in 1?

Docs are here: [Sequelize find](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#find-search-for-one-specific-element-in-the-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.find({
  where: Sequelize.or({ username: 'bryan' }, { email: 'bryan@foo.com' })
});
```

http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sequelize/#orargs-sequelizeor

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if it's built into Sequelize, but good old SQL does the trick:

```
User.find({
  where: ["username = ? OR email = ?", "bryan", "bryan@foo.com"]
}).then(...)
```

Open to marking a correct answer that shows it through a Sequelize syntax as well.